# Retaining drawings in gtkmm using queue_draw

Tags: cairo, gtkmm, drawingarea

I want to draw multiple entities in drawing area. The background is painted every time queue_draw function is called.

```
bool DrawingArea::on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr)
{
cr->set_source_rgb(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);   // white background
cr->paint();

cr->set_line_width(2.0);

if(entity == 1)  // draw point
{
cr->set_source_rgb(0.0, 0.26, 0.26);
cr->save();
cr->arc(205.0, 110.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2 * M_PI); // full circle        
cr->restore();  
cr->stroke();
}

if(entity == 2)  // draw line
{
cr->set_source_rgb(0.0, 0.26, 0.26);
cr->save();
cr->move_to(0,0);
cr->line_to(100,100);
cr->restore();  
cr->stroke();
}
    return true;
}
```

The above code works when queue_draw function in the following code is called:

```
void DrawingArea :: on_point_cb()
{
entity = 1;
queue_draw();
std::cout<<"Point created"<<std::endl;
}
```

When a new entity is selected to be drawn, the previous one gets erased. What should be done so that the previous entity drawn persists?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of drawing to the screen on the redraw event, draw instead to a surface and keep that surface around.

When the on_draw function is called, simply repaint the stored surface, that way you decide what persists and what doesn't.

Drawing to the stored surface will persist the changes across redraws, where as drawing to the cairo surface provided to you inside the on_draw function will always be erased between calls.

Hope it helps, I know this is an old question.